# retrieving all users from group [laravel]

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have 3 groups and 16 users belonging to these groups randomly.
I am using

```
$groups = \App\Group::with('users')->get();
```

operand to get groups and users.
But i only have 1 group filled with users, others group (which is linked in intermediate table) are empty.

In Group model i have these:

```
class Group extends Model
{
protected $table = 'crm_groups';
protected $primaryKey = 'group_id';
protected $fillable = ['name'];
public $timestamps = true;

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'crm_user_groups', 'user_id', 'group_id');
}
```

}

Database:

```
 INSERT INTO `crm_user_groups` (`id`, `group_id`, `user_id`) VALUES
 (1,    1,  1),
 (2,    2,  1),
 (3,    2,  1),
 (4,    3,  1),
 (5,    2,  14),
 (6,    2,  15),
 (7,    3,  16);
```

Comment: Can you share your model relationship and database field?

Comment: added in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've passed the wrong place of your param.

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('\App\User', 'crm_user_groups','group_id', 'user_id');
}
```

If you're accessing it from Group model then the first param should be `'group_id'` and then `'user_id'`.

The **third argument** is the foreign key name of the **model on which you are defining** the relationship, while the **fourth argument** is the **foreign key name of the model** that you are joining to.